# Cómo comparar dos collections en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collectionjs

Estoy comenzando con MongoDB... Trabajo con JavaScript y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de comparar dos colecciones de MongoDB (van a ser muy similares en datos). Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
/* A - Coleccion Clientes */

/* Cliente 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db04"),
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "telefono" : "666123456",
        "email" : "fulanito@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "Fulanito",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d448")
    },
    "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2017-09-04T10:26:22.300Z")
}

/* B - Coleccion OCR */

/* Datos OCR 1 */

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db05"),
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "email" : "fulanito22@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "",
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d405")
    },
    "fechaInforme" : ISODate("2017-09-04T11:26:22.300Z")
}
```

Después de comprar, quiero insertar los campos diferentes en otra colección "errores". La colección correcta será la de clientes y los datos diferentes o que falte en la colección OCR se insertarán en "errores".

**¿Cómo puedo comparar las dos colecciones y guardar las diferencias?** ¿Hay alguna forma "intuitiva" o tengo que hacerlo campo a campo?

PD. Necesito que se guarden tanto los atributos del json A que no estén en B (por ejemplo "teléfono" y su valor), como aquellos atributos que están en ambos json pero su valor es diferente (Por ejemplo, "email")

Comment: Aquí puedes comparar dos cosas: Si los objetos tienen los mismos atributos o si los objetos tienen los mismos atributos y valores. A lo que veo, quieres saber sólo si tienen los mismos atributos, pero un objeto también puede considerarse diferente a otro si el valor de un atributo es diferente, así que ¿Qué tipo de diferencias son las que necesitas?

Comment: A lo mejor no está bien explicado, tienes razón, ahora lo editaré. Quiero guardar ambas cosas, tanto si el atributo es distinto (por ejemplo el json A lo tiene y el B no), como si lo tienen los dos pero su valor es diferente. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra opción mucha más sencilla es usar el paquete [deep-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff).

**Ejemplo**

```js
/* Cliente 1 */
const c1 = {
    "_id" : "1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db04",
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "telefono" : "666123456",
        "email" : "fulanito@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "Fulanito",
        "_id" : "59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d448"
    },
    "fechaCreacion" : "2017-09-04T10:26:22.300Z"
};

/* Datos OCR 1 */

const c2 = {
    "_id" : "1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db05",
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "email" : "fulanito22@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "",
        "_id" : "59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d405"
    },
    "fechaInforme" : "2017-09-04T11:26:22.300Z"
};

var diff = DeepDiff.noConflict();
console.log(diff(c1, c2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/deep-diff/0.3.3/deep-diff.min.js"></script>
```

Este paquete te genera un objeto con las diferencias entre dos objetos y te indica el tipo de diferencia:

> - N - indicates a newly added property/element
> - D - indicates a property/element was deleted
> - E - indicates a property/element was edited
> - A - indicates a change occurred within an array

Lo que sí debes asegurarte es transformar tanto el `ISODate` como el `ObjectId` a texto plano antes de evaluar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar, ya que los json que tengo son muy extensos (los acorté para el ejemplo). Cómo podría hacer para convertir ISODate y ObjectId?

Comment: Para `ObjectId` puedes usar el método [`valueOf`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/) y para `ISODate`el método `toJSON`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado lo que buscas [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432188/8220227).

Con esta función se consigue comparar una collection con la otra y obtienes las diferencias.

```
function filter(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = {};
    for(key in obj1) {
        if(obj2[key] != obj1[key]) result[key] = obj2[key];
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'array' && typeof obj1[key] == 'array') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'object' && typeof obj1[key] == 'object') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Añado un snippet con tu ejemplo.

```js
/* Coleccion Clientes */

/* Cliente 1 */
var obj1 ={
    "_id" : "1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db04",
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "telefono" : "666123456",
        "email" : "fulanito@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "Fulanito",
        "_id" : "59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d448"
    },
    "fechaCreacion" : "2017-09-04T10:26:22.300Z"
}

/* Coleccion OCR */

/* Datos OCR 1 */

var obj2 ={
    "_id" :"1b35f0eb1d86f527f646db05",
    "numero" : 1,
    "datosCliente" : {
        "nifCif" : "72928177D",
        "email" : "fulanito22@correo.com",
        "nombre" : "",
        "_id" : "59ad2a4e39b9350d7296d405"
    },
    "fechaInforme" : "2017-09-04T11:26:22.300Z"
}

function filter(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = {};
    for(key in obj1) {
        if(obj2[key] != obj1[key]) result[key] = obj2[key];
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'array' && typeof obj1[key] == 'array') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        if(typeof obj2[key] == 'object' && typeof obj1[key] == 'object') 
            result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(filter(obj1,obj2));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me da algunos problemas en un json muy extenso pero se acerca a ser una buena solución, gracias!