# Mongodb: Comparar dos colecciones y eliminar documentos repetidos

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, insert, collectionjs

Trabajo en una empresa que realiza el servicio de cobros a los clientes de bancos (los bancos son clientes nuestros) y hago mención de esto para que no se piense que lo hago con fines no legales.

¿Cual es el mejor mecanismo para eliminar datos ya existentes en otra colección?

Estamos desarrollando un sistema de cobranzas en el cual es necesario importar una buena cantidad de cuentas de clientes hacia una colección temporal (Podemos importar hasta 100 mil registros por importación, y este proceso puede ser diario). **El problema está en que en dicha colección temporal** **existen datos de clientes que ya están registrados en otra colección (Permanente).**

**¿Cuál es el mecanismo ideal para importar todas esas cuentas y compararlas (por su documento de identidad) con los documentos de clientes ya existentes en otra colección?**

Encontré [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99659/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-dos-collections-en-mongodb) pero no estoy seguro que sea capaz de encontrar diferencias en tantos registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mis propósitos, el método [bulk.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/) de **Mongodb** soluciona mi problema. ¿Cómo funciona? ¿Cómo lo logré?

1. Preparé mi colección definiendo un indice único.
2. Utilicé el método bulk insert y lo preparé de la siguiente forma:

   **bulk.insert({ 
       id_cliente: linea[ 0 ],
       iddoi: linea[ 1 ],
       id_personeria: linea[ 2 ],
       liente: linea[ 3 ]
   });**
3. Este tipo de objetos los creé utilizando un bucle for, donde añadí todos los elementos a insertar.
4. Finalizada la inclusión utilicé **bulk.execute().**

Eso fue suficiente. Este método lo que hace es ingresar solo aquellos que no se repitan, no es necesario hacer la comparación, extraer los que no se repitan e insertar los registros. Super ahorro.

Para el que le sirva.

Comment: ¿En el código usaste mongoose o directamente mongodb?

Comment: No usé Mongoose. Solo MongoDb.

Comment: ok, gracias por compartirlo